# Recover GPT Unformatted Partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, gpt

I have a 500GB HDD, with a partition that I tried to move.

After moving it, I found it is still in the starting place, but now I don't have access to it anymore.

[image: disk partitions]

I tried to recover it with [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com) partition recovery, but it can't fix `GPT` disk, so i tried with EaseUS Data Recovery, and it seems it can read the files that were on the disc, in fact it can read all the files I need

My problem is that I don't have enough space to copy it, so I need to restore this partition without losing data.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can copy your data to an external or another internal disk if you don't have enough space on your current disk.

Comment: anyway the recovery programs i have don't recreate all the directory structure, they just find the file and their contents, it would be impossible to fix 310 GB of files, do you know some good program for it?

Comment: Yes, i personally have had some problems with HDDs and i used "recover my files" to get my data back. it keeps the structure of files and folders when recovering them. you can try it as trial to see if it successfully recognizes all of your files/folders but when you want to save them, you need to activate it.

Comment: there's no way to fix the partition insthead of recovering and then reformatting?

Comment: You mentioned that you tried to move your partition (i can't imagine how!) and you currently don't have access to it. so you better not to do anything to prevent overriding your data and try a recovery program. there's also a free software that's said to be useful. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: The problem is that all theese programs recover only the file that they can discover, like images, videos, and similiar files, but what about particolar files?

Comment: I don't think it's like that. most programs i worked with doesn't care about the file's extension, instead they try to recover the file itself, raw data. what is the extension of the file you're talking about?

Comment: i'm a programmer, i have a lot of different filetypes created by various programs created by me, if thoose program search a pre-defined start of the file (like it say http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) so they won't be able to recognize most of my file, that's why since i can see some files i think partition is not destroyed, maybe it's just the partition table or the filesystem is damaged

Comment: If the partition table is damaged then the "TestDisk" program (found in the same website) can fix it. when you recover your drive using raw recovery, all of your files will be recovered regardless of their extension.

Comment: i tried using testdisk, but basically it do some output that are different from guides, and i don't know how to proceed

Comment: anyway another problem about using the raw recover is that i loose all filenames and directory names, and i can't manually sort more than 300 GB

Comment: You said that when you used "EaseUS" it did find all of your files. "TestDisk" might be risky if you accidentally rewrite partition structure. i suggest you to try "Recover my files" and see if it can read all of your files. if it can then you temporary need another hard disk to copy your recovered file to it.

Comment: I realized there's something strange: it find the folder structure and some files, but not all of them, it find the other files in another way, and in that way it doesen't find the folder structure and not even the filename, but i think i just have to give up and recover my file loosing part of the structure... :/

Comment: Which software did you use?

Comment: I used EaseUs Data Recovery Wizard

Comment: You can try Recover my files too.